# how can decode by "EUC-KR" in javascript nodejs(why this string occur "Url malformed" error)

Tags: javascript, decode

```js
//original text : 김상현 (EUC-KR), encode utf-8 result 
const occurErrorEncodedString = '%B1%E8%BB%F3%C7%F6';
decodeURI(occurErrorEncodedString); //Error in This Part
```

this string occur malformed error in javascript decodeUrl function

it encode UTF-8 from EUC-KR
cuz i don't know about percent url form

++
in Kotlin

```kotlin
val decodedString = URLDecoder.decode("%B1%E8%BB%F3%C7%F6","euc-kr")
```

is works, how can i do this in Javascript Nodejs

Comment: Please, provide the original text.

Comment: And how you end up with your result.

Comment: It *is* malformed. There isn't even a scheme name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax

Comment: @EmilKarlsson Same thing when using `decodeURIComponent` instead of `decodeURI` here, though

Comment: That error message is correct. Your URI component sequence is malformed. You can read more about encoding and decoding at [malformed URI sequence (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Malformed_URI#decoding).

Comment: Maybe [this npm package](https://npm.io/package/decode-uri-component-charset) will help. `uec-kr` isn't unicode, so `decodeURI` will have problems with it. You should try to keep everything in unicode when working with javascript.

Answer (score -2):

The decodeUri() function is for parsing complete URLs. You want to parse a part, a component of an url so you have to use the decodeUriComponent() function.

For further information, see the documentation of [decoeUriComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) and [decodeUri()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

**Edit**

The string '김상현' - has correct URI encoded notation
'%EA%B9%80%EC%83%81%ED%98%84'

You can use the encodeURIComponent() function to ensure the proper encoding.

Comment: Using `decodeURIComponent('%B1%E8%BB%F3%C7%F6')` still throws an exception

Comment: @Bergi yes i try decodeURIComponent too. for that string only, this error occurs in either of them

Comment: You can decode URI component with `decodeURI()` too.

Comment: Ah it's an encoding problem - those functions only work on utf8. How do you create the string?